# Configuring Geany to Execute files/packages in a seperate folder

Tags: java, ubuntu, ide, geany

I recently downloaded Geany onto my new Ubuntu machine and I am very satisfied with it overall, but after days of fiddling with the Build Commands, I am still unable to Execute .class files outputted to `~/Documents/classes/` from .java files in `~/Documents/src/`.

I tried creating a custom command (`cd ~/Documents/classes/`) to be run after Compile and before Execute, but Geany throws the error message `/bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to /home/leon/Document/classes/` when I press it. I have not been able to Execute packages either. Is it possible to solve these issues rather than simply getting around the problem by using the command line? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this into a Makefile -- or a small 3 line shell script and using this.